2D semiconductors, and their practical applications
I understand that there are many complications with 2D semiconductors!(1) However, I wanted to know whether there are any practical uses of 2D semiconductors in consumer products.
I tried searching online as well, but most research hinted towards 2D semiconductors still being in development. So would this mean that it is still in development, or have there been any applications that I perhaps wasn't able to find.
(1)https://qs3.mit.edu/images/pdf/WhyAllTheFussAbout2Dsemiconductors.pdf

Who is this "Semi Conductor"? Seriously, Wikipedia already has a list of applications with decent references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_semiconductor

Yeah, I understand that. But I was wondering whether there are companies utilising it in their products? Products that are being sold in the market.

A looking for commercial 2D-semiconductor devices on the web showed only a few items, e.g.,

Search on "commercial graphene transistor" returned devices from MSE Supplies.
Search on "copper indium gallium selenide solar cell" found this report from Sino Voltaics, showing their portion of the existing market.

As you speculate, 2D electronics is more in the stage of research and development, without many products in the market -- except, thin-film solar cells, which do seem to be selling well.
